# Samsung Note 2 input language selector problem (Android 4.3)

Tags: keyboard, 4.3-jelly-bean, languages, samsung-galaxy-note-2

I have a strange problem for about a week. I have 3 input languages enabled on my smartphone (EN, RU, DE). To switch between them, I usually could slide the space-bar of the on-screen keyboard to the left or to the right.

However, recently this function has suddenly disappeared. The triangles do not appear on the space bar. I've found a few other posts on the internet, and there the authors connect it to the 4.3 Android upgrade. I am not sure though. I thought I upgraded quite a while ago and everything was OK. But I may be wrong.

Interestingly, if I switch to the hand-writing mode by tapping the "T"-button to the left from the space bar, the triangles appear on the space bar and I can now switch the language.

Any ideas?

Comment: In my case it was Greenify menu in Accessibility

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had faced the same problem myself.

System settings > device > accessibility > services.
Something in there is set to On. Switch it to off and you will be OK. I had the same problem because I had an application set to on.  Instant fix!

Comment: Amazing! It's the new LastPass autofill feature. Who would have thought! I've switched it off, and now the language switching is back. Thanks a lot! Will notify LastPass.

Comment: Actually,  you enabled it because it needed your permission but when you updated to Android 4.3 that permission was not necessary so it conflicted with your system.  Cheers!

Comment: Reported: https://forums.lastpass.com/viewtopic.php?f=14&t=126325

Comment: Mine was because of Master clean to extend the battery life. I switched that off and it worked Note3

Answer (score 1):

For Me the solution was similar but different. I had nothing under the accessibility options excepted "Talkback" turned off. I turned it on then off and VOILA! it brought back the arrows.

Comment: Amro Elfiky thank you very much
I had the same problem and you helped me solve it, you are awesome :)))))))))))